# Open a Visual force page as pop up from another visual force page with parameters

Tags: apex, javascript, javascript-remoting

I am having a visual force page with a button. On click of a button, I need to open another visual force page as popup. Also, I want to parameters through that as well .

I am able to do so using following code. But What I want is another page. Please suggest how can this be 
achieved.

> ```
>     function hideshow(which){
>     if (!document.getElementById)
>     return
>     if (which.style.display=="block")
>     which.style.display="none"
>     else
>     which.style.display="block"
>     }
> ```
>
> ```
> <apex:form >
>     <div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; display: block">Now you see me</div>
>
>            <apex:commandButton value="Show Pop up" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
>                <apex:pageBlock >
>                     This is just filler text from the Salesforce General. 
>                </apex:pageBlock>
>
>                 <apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
>                 <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
>                 <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
>                         This is where I would put whatever information I needed to show to my end user.<br/><br/><br/>
>
>
>                <apex:pageBlock title="Search" >
>                     <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" id="theSearchstring" maxlength="100" size="100"/>
>                         &nbsp;
> <apex:commandButton value="Go" id="submitButton" style="width:30" reRender="theSearchResults" /> </apex:pageBlock> <apex:messages />
> ```
>
> Title Article
>   Type Summary  
>       {!article.title}
>
> ```
>                        <!-- // working code <a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('article'))">Click
> ```
>
> Here 
>    {!answer}  
>   -->   {!article.articleTypeLabel}   {!article.abstract}  
>      Show
>   details
>
> ```
>             <apex:commandButton value="Hide Pop up" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
>
>         </apex:outputPanel>
>
>
>
>        <apex:define name="body"></apex:define> 
>     </apex:outputPanel>
>
> </apex:form>
>
> <style type="text/css">
>     .custPopup{
>         background-color: white;
>         border-width: 3px;
>         border-style: solid;
>         z-index: 9999;
>         left: 40%;
>         padding:10px;
>         position: absolute;
>         /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to change so the popup 
>         displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
>         margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can add 
>         the height property for a fixed size pop up if you want.*/
>         width: 700px;
>         margin-left: -250px;
>         top:100px;
>     }
>     .popupBackground{
>         background-color:black;
>         opacity: 0.20;
>         filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
>         position: absolute;
>         width: 100%;
>         height: 100%;
>         top: 0;
>         left: 0;
>         z-index: 9998;
>     }
>  td{ vertical-align : top; text-align: left; }
>
>
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well how about this if you are ok with opening in a new tab

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/SomePage" target="_blank"  >
    Click
    <apex:param name="query" value="somevalue"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

if not then you would have to go for some JavaScript

```
<apex:outputLink   onclick="openPopup('{!$Page.PageDemo}','somevalue');">
    Click
</apex:outputLink>

<script>
function openPopup(page,param){
    window.open(page+'?param='+param,'_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400')
}
</script>
```

Comment: It will open the page in a new window rather than a popup

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try with JS - `Window.open(URL,Name,specs)`;

**Sample code**:

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.in','Google','height=200,width=200');">
  Click
</button>
```

For more details, please refer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp